# rails fullcalendar javascript callbacks not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I am trying to integrate fullcalendar in my rails project. I installed the gem and the dependencies (moment.js gem)

The calendar appears but the callbacks within the calendar aren't working.

This is in my custom.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function() {
        alert('a day has been clicked!');
    }
    });
});
```

This is my index.html.haml:

```
.row
    .col-lg-12
        #calendar
```

The calendar appears but when I click on a day the alert does not happen. I have simplified the fullCalendar method so that it only has that one callback now. I assume that it is something wrong with the asset pipeline. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: So I ended up figuring it out. I went with just including the js and css files in the asset folder. The problem was that fullcalendar.print.css was messing everything up so I didn't that and it worked!